# curl error when sending the data

Tags: php, curl

Upon visiting a given link using my browser, it's working just as planned. However, when I'm trying to access it via cURL, it just isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $url='http://example.com';
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? What's the error message?

Comment: ...and what does "through file" mean? I don't see any file-related snippets.

Comment: ^^ he meant through cURL (I suppose)

Comment: @Maerlyn no error message at all.

Comment: @Ashutosh You'd better show the error message in your question. Otherwise it is hard to know what is wrong just by the two words 'not working'...

Comment: @xdazz it is not giving any error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you 100% positive you enabled lib_curl in php.ini? A blank cURL response is most likely due to the module not being enabled. Try the below:

```
$ch = curl_init( "http://stackoverflow.com" );
var_dump ( curl_exec( $ch ));
```

if there is output, the page could be redirecting you, in which case try adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)     // follow redirects

CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true   // may also help depending on the site...
```

Comment: as I suspected, libcurl is not enabled. Open your php.ini file and look for this line: 
;extension=php_curl.dll 

remove the ";" then retry. If that does not work please post the result of the following code:  

<?php 
## Test if cURL is working ## 
## SCRIPT BY WWW.WEBUNE.COM (please do not remove)## 
echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump(curl_version()); 
echo '</pre>'; 
?>

Comment: it gives  array(9) {
  ["version_number"]=>
  int(464131)
  ["age"]=>
  int(3)
  ["features"]=>
  int(1597)
  ["ssl_version_number"]=>
  int(0)
  ["version"]=>
  string(6) "7.21.3"
  ["host"]=>
  string(17) "i686-pc-linux-gnu"
  ["ssl_version"]=>
  string(14) "OpenSSL/0.9.8o"
  ["libz_version"]=>
  string(7) "1.2.3.4"

Comment: Interesting... it looks like your libcurl is setup correctly, but this is definitely not a code related issue. It looks like you are running linux, maybe try reinstalling the associated packages. On a debian system you would run "sudo apt-get install --reinstall curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl"..might have to go so far as purging configs, but it is for sure a server issue.

Comment: Crazy... Sorry I'm out of ideas (assuming you restarted apache) :( . Might be a good idea to hit up forums for your linux distro...possibly also apache/php but I bet it's something OS side...firewall maybe...?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable lib curl?

[on XAMPP](http://www.tildemark.com/programming/php/enable-curl-with-xampp-on-windows-xp.html)
[on WAMP](http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp/)

---

```
$url='http://example.com';
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,30); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0'); 
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    echo $rawdata;
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: i have checked that by fetching other url.its working :(. m using LAMP

Comment: `echo $rawdata;` or `var_dump($rawdata);`

Comment: var_dump($rawdata) gives string(0) ""

Comment: added useragent, try this code. (I suppose your website doesn't want to show up to bots, people usually do that to avoid spam)

Comment: http://api.myvaluefirst.com/psms/servlet/psms.Eservice2?data=%3C?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?%3E %3C!DOCTYPE MESSAGE SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1/psms/dtd/messagev12.dtd" %3E %3CMESSAGE VER="1.2"%3E %3CUSER USERNAME="name" PASSWORD="password"/%3E %3CSMS UDH="0" CODING="1" TEXT="lets do it once" PROPERTY="0" ID="1"%3E %3CADDRESS FROM="mishra" TO="1111111111" SEQ="1" TAG="some clientside random data" /%3E %3C/SMS%3E %3C/MESSAGE%3E&action=send

Comment: my money is on a silent redirect.  see my answer, this caught me out the other day.